# Redireccionar después de usar la función header para descargar un archivo excel

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario de alta empresa cuando este es llenado se genera un *Excel* y se descarga con claves de usuario según el número que se pone en el registro mi problema es que trato de redireccionar una vez que el registro esta completo y descargar el *Excel* sin embargo solo puede realizar una de estas funciones.

¿Cómo podría realizar la redirección o mostrar un mensaje de éxito y limpiar pantalla además de que se descargue el *Excel*?

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['guardar']))
   {

  

    $cct=$_POST['cct'];
    $empresa=$_POST['empresa'];
    $planta=$_POST['planta'];
    $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
    $num=$_POST['cantidad'];
    $clave=$_POST['admin'];  
     
    
    
    if ($clave=="Sisnom035#") 
    {
         
    //abrir base de datos
     include("../../bd/abrir_bd.php");
    
    $consulta="INSERT INTO $tabla (id_empresa,empresa,planta,direccion,empleados) VALUES ('$cct','$empresa','$planta','$direccion','$num')";
   
     
     if (mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta))
     {
    //Esta es la parte donde se genera el excel y donde ya no puedo redireccionar
       **header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=iso-8859-15');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=claves.xls');**    
  
      ?>  
      <table class="table">
   
     <tr>
     <th>Usuario</th>
     <th>Password</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     </tr>   
     <?php   
          for ($i=0; $i<$num ; $i++)
           { 
          $letras='abcdfghijklmnopkrstuvwxyz0123456789';
          $longletras=strlen($letras);
          $letras1='abcdfghijklmnopkrstuvwxyz0123456789';
          $longletras1=strlen($letras1);
          $letras2='abcdfghijklmnopkrstuvwxyz0123456789';
          $longletras2=strlen($letras2);
          $clave=rand(100,999);
          $letra=$letras[rand(0,$longletras-1)];
          $letra1=$letras1[rand(0,$longletras1-1)];
          $letra2=$letras2[rand(0,$longletras2-1)];
          $pass=$letra.$letra1.$clave.$letra2;

         echo "<tr> 
             <td>$cct</td>
             <td>$pass</td>";

            $consulta2="INSERT INTO claves (codigo,id_empresa) VALUES ('$pass','$cct')";
            if (mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta2))
             {

               $message = "Datos Guardados Con exito";
               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
               window.location.href='../../prueba.html';
               </script>";
             //   echo "<td>guardado</td> 
            //     </tr>";
              }
             else
                {
                  $message = "Los Datos no se Guardaron Intentalo de nuevo";
                  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
                  window.location.href='../../prueba.html';
                  </script>";
                //   echo "<td>No se guardo</td>
               //          </tr>";
                    --$i;
                 }          
             }         
       } //la empresa se guardo
        else
          {
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("La Empresa no se guardo");
                location.href ="altaempresa.html";
                </script>
            <?php   
                 include("../../bd/cerrar_bd.php");
                 exit();
           }    
    
       //cerrar base de datos
        include("../../bd/cerrar_bd.php");
     } //admin valido
     else
      {
         ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Administrador no valido");
          location.href ="altaempresa.html";
          </script>         
          <?php
          include("../../bd/cerrar_bd.php");
          exit();   
       }   
   }//si se presiono boton guardar(isset)  
?>
```

Comment: Ese isset esta validando si presiono en el boton guardar cierto? simplemente añade al final de la linea, es decir, if(...){ ..Codigo... header('location: tupagina.php'); }

Comment: Estoy viendo que dentro de esa validacion del boton haces una nueva comparacion con la contraseña, si la contraseña es valida entra en el bucle donde registra da el excel etc.. despues de alli puedes añadir el header seria algo como  if ($clave=="Sisnom035#") 
    { ...Codigo... header('location: pagina.php');}

Comment: @ernestojimenez lo he intententado coloque el header antes de cerrar el if si me redirecciona pero no descarga el excel

Comment: Pero si te descarga el excel si no lo pones?

Comment: @ernestojimenez  si pongo el location:"mipagina.php" solo me redirige pero no descarga el archivo y si no lo pongo solo descarga el excel pero no redirecciona